# Display a list of specific WooCommerce catagories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We currently have a list of categories for each product displayed.

We want to hide some specific categories from the front-end because they are only for admin purpose. So ideally we want to determine which categories are included? The code snippet is below.

```
        Catagories: <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
$product_cat = array();

foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $product_cat[] .= $term->name;
}

echo implode(', ', $product_cat); ?>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

Specify restricted categories in $restricted_cats array with slugs of that categories. Then you can check if the category is in array of restricted categories. You could also check the term ids instead of slugs, since both are unique.

```
Catagories: <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
$product_cat = array();
$restricted_cats = array("term-slug", "term-slug2", "term-slug3", "term-slug4")

foreach ($terms as $term) {
   if (!in_array($term->slug, $restricted_cats)) {
      $product_cat[] .= $term->name;
   }
}

echo implode(', ', $product_cat); ?>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! This works although it excludes the category. How would I do it if I want to specify what category is included? There are more we wan to exclude than include so this would make things easier.

Comment: Never mind I figured out a solution myself. All it needed was an 'else'

Answer (score 1):

You can alter what product cats are shown (or not) using Woocommerce's `woocommerce_product_subcategories_args` filter, thus:

```
// Remove categories from loop.
function ma_exclude_wlb_loop( $args ) {
    $cats_to_hide = array( 23, 44, 93 );
    if ( !is_admin() ) :
        $myargs = $args["exclude"];
        if ( !$myargs ) $myargs = array();
        if ( !is_array( $myargs ) ) $myargs = explode( ",", $myargs );
        $cats_to_hide = $cats_to_hide;
        $args["exclude"] = array_merge( $cats_to_hide, $myargs );
    endif;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'ma_exclude_wlb_loop' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is something else to consider but for our purposes I think the solution by @gregor best fits the job.

Comment: This code needs polishing, but `woocommerce_product_subcategories_args` is still a very good catch to manage subcategory visibility. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this Woocommerce Shortcode

```
[woocommerce_product_filter_category include="clothing,shoes,jackets,shirts,shorts" show_thumbnails="yes"]
```

You can get more information this site https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/woocommerce_product_filter_category/

Comment: This is not what we want at all. Thanks though